# Session variable in MVC with jQuery Ajax post

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, session-variables

I am using ASP.Net MVC 5 to build a web application and using jQuery along with it. I have kind of a single page application where I use the index action set a session variable and display the view. Further I using jQuery to invoke Get and Post Ajax request to actions on the same controllers. The problem is in accessing the Sesssion variable. I am setting the session variable in the index action and trying to access the same variable in the post action invoked by jquery. Please suggest if there is something that I am missing.

My Controller class is something like below:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
    {
        var obj = new SomeObject();
        Session["UserName"] = Request.QueryString["UserName"];

        return View(obj);
    }

    //Invoked by jQuery Ajax method..
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("home/GetResponse/")]
    public async Task<JsonResult> GetResponse(string message)
    {
        var userName = Convert.ToString(Session["UserName"]);// Getting Null
        //Perform some stuff and return json
    }
}
```

Comment: Show your code ,

Comment: if possible you can try with tempdata thanks

Answer (score 0):

Session variable is constant in single page that means it will not change if page is not loaded or refreshed.
So in Success of Ajax submit you have to place the value of the session manually.
if `<span id="demoid">@session["client_name"]</span>`

then

```
       success: function(data)
       {
           $("#demoid").html(data);  // here data is the value for the session
       }
```